bitcoin synchonization problem
this is shiva from india andiam invested 200 dollors on bitcoin and iam try to sychonize bitcoincore from past 7 months it is very slow i cant unerstand what should i do now

Hi shiva, what kind of system are you running this on? (CPU, RAM, disk etc.)

Are you able to let the computer run continuously (24/7) with Bitcoin core running all the time?

Hey shiva, 7 months sounds really odd. Could you please add more information to your question how often you are running Bitcoin Core and how long? Do you shut down Bitcoin Core cleanly when you turn off your computer? Is it possible that you have rescan in the configuration and you start over every time? Are you sure that you got a legit copy of Bitcoin Core? Where did you download it?
